# Create Word doc from Excel: Automation Error The remote procedure call failed

Tags: vba, ms-word, excel-365

I have been going round in circles and am probably looking at the issue but can't see it anymore. I am creating a word document using two excel workbooks and a word template but
I keep getting a Automation Error: The remote procedure call failed and it will stop on any one of the .typeParagraph lines when I debug.  Usually it is near the end after pasting one of the DTStudy ranges.  This doesn't happen every time I run the script but once it starts happening it continues for each subsequent execution.

I have tried fixing up any late binding and adding error handlers and a clear clipboard API and it looked like it was working but then I run the script again and get the error.  I am also randomly getting a PasteSpecial error for DTStudy2 no matter what I change that line to but it is not happening on every execution.

It may be that I have a made a mess of my code and it just needs tidying up but I have run out of ideas after extensive searching through multiple forums.  Any suggestions to improve this and stop the errors from crashing word would be most appreciated.

```
Sub CreateWordDoc()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application ''' Declare ExcelApp as Excel.Application type
    Dim twb As Excel.Workbook ''' Declare twb as Excel.Workbook type
    Dim twbSheet As Excel.Worksheet ''' Declare twbSheet as Excel.Worksheet type
    Set ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
    Set twb = ThisWorkbook

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        '''Copy from Report Template
            Dim CellValue As Variant
            Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
            Dim wbPath As String
    
            ''' Define the path to the workbook to open
            wbPath = "C:\Users\Document Template v5.xlsx"
            
            ''' Check if the workbook is already open
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wb = Workbooks(wbPath)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            ''' If the workbook is closed, open it
            If wb Is Nothing Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
            End If
            
        wb.Windows(1).Visible = True
        
    Set twbSheet = twb.Worksheets("Input Data")
    Dim twbSheetGeo As Excel.Worksheet:      Set twbSheetGeo = twb.Worksheets("Geotechnical Report")
    Dim twbSheetRev As Excel.Worksheet:      Set twbSheetRev = twb.Worksheets("Revisions")
    Dim twbSheetCS As Excel.Worksheet:       Set twbSheetCS = twb.Worksheets("Control Sheet")
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet:            Set ExcelWorksheet = wb.Worksheets("Section1")
    Dim ExcelWorksheetS2 As Excel.Worksheet:          Set ExcelWorksheetS2 = wb.Worksheets("Section2")
    Dim ExecSummWS As Excel.Worksheet:       Set ExecSummWS = wb.Worksheets("ExecSummary")
    Dim ExecSumm As Range:          Set ExecSumm = ExecSummWS.Range("ExecSummary")
    Dim BldgPF As Range:            Set BldgPF = ExecSummWS.Range("BldgPF")
    ''' Set the RGB color values
    Dim RedValue As Integer:        RedValue = 111
    Dim GreenValue As Integer:      GreenValue = 1
    Dim BlueValue As Integer:       BlueValue = 3

                Dim IntroBP As Excel.Range
                Set IntroBP = ExcelWorksheet.Range("Intro")
                    Dim xlRange As Object
                    Set xlRange = IntroBP
                Dim SDExample As Excel.Range:         Set SDExample = ExcelWorksheet.Range("SiteDescExample")
                Dim PropDev As Excel.Range:           Set PropDev = ExcelWorksheet.Range("PropDev")
                  CellValueA2 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A2").Value
                  CellValueA3 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A3").Value
                  CellValueB3 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("B3").Value
                  CellValueC3 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("C3").Value
                  CellValueB4 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("B4").Value
                  CellValueA5 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A5").Value
                  CellValueB5 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("B5").Value
                  CellValueA6 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A6").Value
                  CellValueB6 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("B6").Value
                  CellValueA12 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A12").Value
                  CellValueB12 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("B12").Value
                  CellValueA13 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A13").Value
                  CellValueB13 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("B13").Value
                  CellValueA14 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A14").Value
                  CellValueB14 = ExcelWorksheet.Range("B14").Value
            Dim DTStudy1 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy1 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy1")
            Dim DTStudy2 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy2 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("B3:B9")
            Dim DTStudy3 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy3 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy3")
            Dim DTStudy4 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy4 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy4")
            Dim DTStudy5 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy5 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy5")
            Dim DTStudy6 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy6 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy6")
            Dim DTStudy7 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy7 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy7")
            Dim DTStudy8 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy8 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy8")
            Dim DTStudy9 As Excel.Range:        Set DTStudy9 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy9")
            Dim DTStudy10 As Excel.Range:       Set DTStudy10 = ExcelWorksheetS2.Range("DTStudy10")
                  
 '''Copy from current workbook
    Dim Client As Variant
    Dim Address As Variant
    Dim Res As Variant
    Dim Res1 As Variant
    Dim RevTable As Excel.Range
    Dim ClientHeading As String
    Dim tbl As Object ''' Word table object
    Dim xlSigGS As Object
    Dim xlSigNS As Object
    Dim xlSigCG As Object
    Dim xlSigJH As Object
    Dim Designer As Range
    Dim DesignerHdr As Range
    Dim DesignerLU As Variant
    Dim DesignerResult As Variant
    Dim ReviewerLU As Variant
    Dim ReviewerResult As Variant
    Dim ApproverLU As Variant
    Dim ApproverResult As Variant
    Dim DesignerSigName As String
    Dim Appli As Variant
    Client = twbSheet.Range("I33").Value
    Address = twbSheet.Range("I20").Value
    Appli = twbSheetGeo.Range("H11").Value
    Dim GeoMaptbl As Range:         Set GeoMaptbl = ExcelWorksheetS2.ListObjects("GeoMap").DataBodyRange
    Dim GeoMapLU As Variant:            GeoMapLU = twbSheetGeo.Range("GeoMap").Value
    Dim GeoMapResult As Variant:        GeoMapResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(GeoMapLU, GeoMaptbl, 2, 0)
    Dim Terraintbl As Range:         Set Terraintbl = ExcelWorksheetS2.ListObjects("Terrain").DataBodyRange
    Dim TerrainLU As Variant:           TerrainLU = twbSheetGeo.Range("Terrain").Value
    Dim TerrainResult As Variant:       TerrainResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TerrainLU, Terraintbl, 2, 0)
    Set RevTable = twbSheetRev.Range("B9:W18")
    
    Set Designer = twbSheetCS.ListObjects("Designer").DataBodyRange
    Set DesignerHdr = twbSheetCS.ListObjects("Designer").HeaderRowRange
    DesignerLU = twbSheet.Range("I28")
    ReviewerLU = twbSheet.Range("I29")
    ApproverLU = twbSheet.Range("I30")
    DesignerSigName = DesignerLU & "Sig"
    ReviewerSigName = ReviewerLU & "Sig"
    ApproverSigName = ApproverLU & "Sig"
    
    Set xlSigD = twbSheetCS.Shapes(DesignerSigName)
    Set xlSigR = twbSheetCS.Shapes(ReviewerSigName)
    Set xlSigA = twbSheetCS.Shapes(ApproverSigName)
        
    ClientHeading = "CLIENT: " & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Client & vbCrLf & "PROJECT TITLE: " & vbTab & vbTab & twbSheet.Range("i18") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "DOCUMENT NUMBER: " & vbTab & twbSheet.Range("i7") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
 Dim TextToInsert As String
    TextToInsert = vbCrLf & CellValueA2 & Client & " " & CellValueA3 & " " & Res & " " & CellValueB4 & " " & Address & vbCrLf & CellValueA5 & CellValueB5 & vbCrLf & CellValueA6 & CellValueB6

    DesignerResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DesignerLU, Designer, WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", DesignerHdr, 0), 0)
    ReviewerResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ReviewerLU, Designer, WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", DesignerHdr, 0), 0)
    ApproverResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ApproverLU, Designer, WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", DesignerHdr, 0), 0)
    DesignerPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DesignerLU, Designer, WorksheetFunction.Match("Position", DesignerHdr, 0), 0)
    ReviewerPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ReviewerLU, Designer, WorksheetFunction.Match("Position", DesignerHdr, 0), 0)
    ApproverPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ApproverLU, Designer, WorksheetFunction.Match("Position", DesignerHdr, 0), 0)

        
     ''' BPR or Subdivision
        If twbSheetGeo.Range("N7") = "BPR" Then
            Res = CellValueB3
        Else
        If twbSheetGeo.Range("N7") = "Subdivision" Then
            Res = CellValueC3
        End If
        End If
         
        If Appli = "Building Consent application" Then
            Res1 = CellValueB14
        End If
 
 Dim TextToInsertIntro As String
    TextToInsertIntro = CellValueA12 & CellValueB12 & CellValueA13 & CellValueB13 & vbCrLf & CellValueA14 & Appli & Res1
            



With wdApp
.Visible = True
.Activate
.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\Template.dotm")
    With .Selection
    '''Page 2
        .BoldRun '''Switch bold on
        .Font.Color = RGB(RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue)
        .TypeText ClientHeading
        .BoldRun '''Switch bold off
            ''' Revision Table
            RevTable.Copy
            .Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=False
            Set tbl = .Tables(1)
            tbl.Select
            .Collapse Direction:=0
            .Range.InsertAfter Chr(13)
            .TypeText vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call ClearClipboard
        .BoldRun '''Switch bold on
        .TypeText "Report Prepared by:" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Reviewed by:" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Approved by:" & vbCrLf
        xlSigD.Copy
        .Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call ClearClipboard
        .TypeText vbTab
        xlSigR.Copy
        .Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call ClearClipboard
        .TypeText vbTab
        xlSigA.Copy
        .Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call ClearClipboard
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText vbCrLf & DesignerResult & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & ReviewerResult & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & ApproverResult
        .TypeText vbCrLf & DesignerPos & vbTab & vbTab & ReviewerPos & vbTab & ApproverPos & vbCrLf
        .BoldRun '''Switch bold off
      
    .InsertBreak Type:=7
    ExecSumm.Copy
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    .InsertAfter vbCrLf
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'''Call ClearClipboard
    BldgPF.Copy
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    .InsertAfter vbCrLf
Call ClearClipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
'''Introduction Page
    .InsertBreak Type:=7
    .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    .TypeText Text:="INTRODUCTION"
    .TypeParagraph
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCentre
            .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Body Text")
        .TypeText TextToInsert
    .TypeParagraph
    xlRange.Copy
    .Paste
Call ClearClipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    .TypeText TextToInsertIntro
    .TypeParagraph
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call ClearClipboard
    
    .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    .TypeText Text:="SITE DESCRIPTION"
    .TypeParagraph
    SDExample.Copy
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
Call ClearClipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .TypeParagraph
    .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    .TypeText Text:="PROPOSED DEVELOPMENT"
    .TypeParagraph
    PropDev.Copy
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call ClearClipboard

'''Section 2
    .InsertBreak Type:=7
    .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    .TypeText Text:="BACKGROUND DESKTOP STUDY"
    .TypeParagraph
If Not DTStudy1 Is Nothing And DTStudy1.Cells.Count > 0 Then
    DTStudy1.Copy
    .Paste
Else
    .TypeText "No data available for DTStudy1"
End If
    .InsertAfter Text:=vbCrLf
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call ClearClipboard

If Not DTStudy2 Is Nothing And DTStudy2.Cells.Count > 0 Then
    DTStudy2.Copy
    .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Else
    .TypeText "No data available for DTStudy2"
End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call ClearClipboard
    .TypeParagraph

If Not DTStudy3 Is Nothing And DTStudy3.Cells.Count > 0 Then
    DTStudy3.Copy
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
Else
    .TypeText "No data available for DTStudy3"
End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .InsertAfter Text:=vbCrLf
Call ClearClipboard
    .TypeParagraph
    .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    .TypeText Text:="PUBLISHED GEOLOGICAL MAPS"
    .TypeParagraph
If Not DTStudy4 Is Nothing And DTStudy4.Cells.Count > 0 Then
    DTStudy4.Copy
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
Else
    .TypeText "No data available for DTStudy3"
End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call ClearClipboard
    .TypeText " " & GeoMapResult
    .TypeParagraph
If Not DTStudy5 Is Nothing And DTStudy5.Cells.Count > 0 Then
    DTStudy5.Copy
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
Else
    .TypeText "No data available for DTStudy5"
End If

Call ClearClipboard

    .TypeParagraph
    .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    .TypeText Text:="DISTRICT LIQUEFACTION VULNERABILITY ASSESSMENT"
    .TypeParagraph
If Not DTStudy6 Is Nothing And DTStudy6.Cells.Count > 0 Then
    DTStudy6.Copy
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
Else
    .TypeText "No data available for DTStudy6"
End If
Call ClearClipboard

'''Save word document  !!!!!!!!! UPDATE TO SAVE AS NEW IF .01 EXISTS  !!!!!!!!!!!!!
 wdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & "RPT-" & twbSheet.Range("I17").Value & "-01.doc"


   End With '''End Selection
End With '''End App loop

''' Clean up


Call ClearClipboard

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    
    wb.Close False
    Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
    Set ExcelWorksheetS2 = Nothing
    Set ExecSummWS = Nothing
    Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
    Set twbSheet = Nothing
    Set twbSheetGeo = Nothing
    Set twbSheetRev = Nothing
    Set twbSheetCS = Nothing
    Set xlSigGS = Nothing
    Set xlSigNS = Nothing
    Set xlSigCG = Nothing
    Set xlSigJH = Nothing
    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set GeoMaptbl = Nothing
    Set Terraintbl = Nothing
    ExcelApp.Quit
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Two things that may be relevant: I don't think you are closing the Word docs after saving them, and you aren't quitting Word after the loop - perhaps a problem with multiple instances of word being created over several runs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I have added in closing the word document and quitting word but I am still getting the same error and word is still crashing

Comment: In addition to closing the Word doc and quitting Word, make sure that you end any existing instances of Word in the Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Delete) under Background processes.

Comment: In case it's a timing issue, try adding `DoEvents` after each time that you copy,  and each time that you paste.  And anywhere else where you want VBA to wait until Windows processes all operations in the queue.

Comment: OP first uses `GetObject()` and only if that fails makes a call to `CreateObject()`, so this code should not create multiple instances of Word...

Comment: No counting chickens too soon (so to speak) but looks like adding in the `DoEvents` addition has stopped the error so far.  Thank you @Domenic

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah, that's very true, cheers!

Comment: @MelForsyth You're very welcome, cheers!

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, quite right!